# How to include xlsx file as data in an R package

Tags: r

Now, I am making some package.
As a test data, I want to include the xlsx file in the package.
However I do not know the methods, so please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by package? What do you mean by "the xlsx file"? What xlsx file?

Comment: Thank your for your quick reply. I use  R language, and in this language  package are made by devtools, include files named R, man, data, ... . The xlsx file means the Excel file whose file extension is xlsx.

Comment: What devtools? What are you talking about?

Comment: I use R, so package means the R's package and devtool are also another package to create packages.

Comment: OK, that would've been important information to include in your question. Why does it always seem to be R questions that are presented without context, without relevant tags, and without even mentioning the language?

Comment: I am sorry, I forget, so I am beginner,

Comment: I use R and I am not sure what you are asking. You want your package to contain an xlsx reader as a dependency?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I mean by ' devtools::use_data()' I could make '.Rda' data, so I want to know the analogy of this code for '.xlsx' format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating an R package, it is often useful to include data either to support functionality or to use in examples.

Usually this data are included in an R data `.Rda` format and not as an excel file. However, there are exceptions.

The approach you take depends on whether the data are for:

- Internal package use only- store as `R/sysdata.rda`
- Exported for users  - store in `/data`
- Raw data which will be processed for some other reason in your package - store in `inst/extdata`
- Purely for unit testing  - put in `/tests` directory

devtools also has a function which can assist: `devtools::use_data()`

I would suggest further reading on including data in R packages here:

[R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)

References: Wickham (2018), R Packages, O'Reilly,  http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

Comment: By 'devtools::use_data() ' , I could  '.Rda' format. So, I will read your linking page. This is just a quick note to thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @JeanBillie. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I appreciate @Dean for useful and quick reply. Also thank you for letting me the clicking the check mark, I do not know about this. I am japanese, I develop some package to implement some hierarchical Bayesian model by Stan language. Your answer has solved a problem which bother me several month. Thank you!!